# What does the following query mean?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Please refer to the following query written in oracle. Can anyone tell me the meaning of the query?

```
select count(*) from dual connect by level <= 5
group by trunc(next_day(trunc(sysdate,'mm')-1, 'sunday') + (level -1)*7,'mm')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you check what group by clause's parts return, it is first day of the current month which evaluates to the first Sunday that follows:

```
SQL> select trunc(sysdate, 'mm') trnc,
  2         next_day(trunc(sysdate, 'mm') - 1, 'sunday') ne_day
  3  from dual;

TRNC       NE_DAY
---------- ----------
01.04.2021 04.04.2021
           ^
           first Sunday in April 2021
```

`connect by` clause returns 5 rows. Which ones? As query selects from `dual` which has only one column (`dummy`) whose value is `'X'`, you wouldn't see much. But if you check what's in the `group by` clause and select those values, you get

```
SQL> select trunc(next_day(trunc(sysdate,'mm')-1, 'sunday') + (level -1)*7,'mm')
  2  from dual
  3  connect by level <= 5;

TRUNC(NEXT
----------
01.04.2021        --> 4 rows of 1st of April 2021
01.04.2021
01.04.2021
01.04.2021
01.05.2021        --> 1 row  of 5th of April 2021

SQL>
```

When you count number of appearances of each of these values (because of the `group by` clause), the final result of query you posted is

```
SQL> select count(*)
  2  from dual
  3  connect by level <= 5
  4  group by trunc(next_day(trunc(sysdate,'mm')-1, 'sunday') + (level -1)*7,'mm');

  COUNT(*)
----------
         1        --> that's for 5th of April 2021
         4        --> that's for 1st of April 2021

SQL>
```